# about CCAssert in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

CCAssert(m_state == kPaddleStateGrabbed, L"Paddle - Unexpected state!");

this is cocos2d-x sample code (TouchesTest).
what's mean 'L' in front of "Paddle - "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L"a string"` simply declares the string as a Unicode string. The string is then not of type `char*` but a `wchar_t`.

[This article](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Advanced_String_Techniques_in_C-Part_I_Unicode.shtml) covers Unicode strings in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

To be simple, it means the string is a type of wstring, which using wchat_t for each of its character, instead of using a normal char*.
C++ treat Languages such as Chinese or Japanese Differently. For those Languages using more than one byte to represent a single character, it uses wchar_t (wide char).